# Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user php artisan test --parallel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to follow the documentation for https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/testing#running-tests-in-parallel and I am running into the following error when running my unit tests against the database in parallel:

Here is the command I am running:

```
php artisan test --parallel --testsuite=Unit
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
2) Tests\Unit\BlueprintRuleUtilTest::testShouldAddDefaultSnowflakeOutsourceCostWillReturnFalse
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user 'nova'@'%' to database 'nova_test_1' (SQL: drop database if exists `nova_test_1`)
```

I realize after reading the docs that multiple databases are being created dynamically and as a result, having 1 set of .env database creds is not going to be able to connect to N amount of db's that are created. Is there a pattern to resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just had this exact same issue and I found this [github repo discussion](https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/112) that helped me a lot, but basically you can try to set the env value of the DB_USERNAME field to root on this process. In the link it is mentioned sail, which I am not using, but I could get it to work locally using this:

```
DB_USERNAME=root php artisan test --parallel --testsuite=Unit
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: yes i think setting it to the root permission is require to create the databases in parallel